# Integrate keen.io json to highcharts js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, keen-io

Anyone can help me to represent this kind of json data into highcharts time series chart. The confusing part is the timeframe I got from this json

```
[
  {
    "value": {
      "registered_user": 12,
      "inactive_user": 5,
      "active_user": 7
    },
    "timeframe": {
      "start": "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end": "2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "registered_user": 30,
      "inactive_user": 10,
      "active_user": 20
    },
    "timeframe": {
      "start": "2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "registered_user": 25,
      "inactive_user": 8,
      "active_user": 17
    },
    "timeframe": {
      "start": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end": "2016-08-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: How you would like to display your chart? do you have some drawing of how it should look? For now I think that you can use tooltip for showing start and end time: http://jsfiddle.net/bfmfj4md/

Comment: Not in comment @GrzegorzBlachliński ... post the fiddle in answer .. it's great demonstration ..

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I want to display it with basic area chart type. But I think your fiddle already solve my prob. I can customize it the way I need. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can preprocess your data a little bit so it will meet your requirements, so each users activity will have specific series. You can also use new Date().getTime() for changing your date string into milliseconds (format accepted by Highcharts datetime xAxis):

```
  var json = [{
    "value": {
      "registered_user": 12,
      "inactive_user": 5,
      "active_user": 7
    },
    "timeframe": {
      "start": "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end": "2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }, {
    "value": {
      "registered_user": 30,
      "inactive_user": 10,
      "active_user": 20
    },
    "timeframe": {
      "start": "2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }, {
    "value": {
      "registered_user": 25,
      "inactive_user": 8,
      "active_user": 17
    },
    "timeframe": {
      "start": "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end": "2016-08-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }];
  var series = [{
    name: 'registered_user',
    data: []
  }, {
    name: 'inactive_user',
    data: []
  }, {
    name: "active_user",
    data: []
  }];
  var startTime;
  Highcharts.each(json, function(p, i) {
    startTime = new Date(p.timeframe.start).getTime();
    series[0].data.push({
      x: startTime,
      y: p.value.registered_user,
      timeFrame: p.timeframe
    });
    series[1].data.push({
      x: startTime,
      y: p.value.inactive_user,
      timeFrame: p.timeframe
    });
    series[2].data.push({
      x: startTime,
      y: p.value.active_user,
      timeFrame: p.timeframe
    });
  });
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/bfmfj4md/